# generate python code from a known object

Tags: python

Suppose I have a Python Class.

I also have an instance from this class.
Is it possible for me to get the object creation line?

i.e.

```
class Fun:
  def __init__(self,x,y,**kwargs):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
      setattr(self, k, v)

fun = Fun(x, y, z=z)
```

Now I have instance of Fun, i.e. fun.
How could I construct a function to return "a python creation line for this object", i.e. "Fun(x, y, z=z)"

Understanding that implementing class specific __str__ might achieve this goal.

However, is there a function that could be applied to general class without class-level specific functions?

Comment: to be more specific,x='a'; y='b'; z='c';fun = Fun(x, y, z=z) and the expected output should be "Fun('a', 'b', z='c')"

Comment: You might want to start by using the `inspect` module on `Fun.__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

The function you seem to want is `repr()`.

You **might** try to use `vars()`, which is the same as `.__dict__` to find an object's attributes and values. This way, you may make a generic `repr()` method, and make other classes inherit it:

```
class ReprMixin(object):

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{klass}({params})'.format(
            klass=self.__class__.__name__,
            params=', '.join(['{}={!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in vars(self).items()]),
        )

class Fun(ReprMixin):
    def __init__(self, x, y, **kwargs):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
              setattr(self, k, v)

fun = Fun(10, 20, z='abc')
print(repr(fun))
>>> Fun(y=20, x=10, z='abc')
```

Note that the order is not guaranteed. Also, `{!r}` means: call `repr()` on the object being formatted.

However, this has some setbacks, because you may not know what type of attribute your class may have, and trying to `eval()` this probably won't work in non-builtin types (such as int, str, list or dict).